# Plotly: Grouped Bar Chart with multiple axes

Tags: python, plot, bar-chart, plotly, multiple-axes

When I set `barmode='group'` in `Layout` while `trace2 = Bar(...,yaxis='y2')`, this leads bars to be stacked or overlayed instead of grouping them. How can I group the bars while having multiple axes?

I went over these but no avail:

- With single Y axis grouped bar chart is shown [here](https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/).
- Multiple axes is also explained [here](https://plot.ly/python/multiple-axes/) and reference for y-axis is available [here](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#YAxis)

Comment: I have the same issue, and I tested that it's broken in their web editor as well, so I filled https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/78. Not sure whether this applies to only some backends or not, but the JS component is the only one with a public bug tracker.

Answer (score 25):

I hope the code below, based on [zoo example](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/), will be self-explanatory, however you have to set `yaxis` and `offsetgroup` parameters in `go.Bar()` object, and also `yaxis2` parameter in `layout` parameter of `go.Figure()` object properly. The code is following:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
animals = ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(name='SF Zoo', x=animals, y=[200, 140, 210], yaxis='y', offsetgroup=1),
        go.Bar(name='LA Zoo', x=animals, y=[12, 18, 29], yaxis='y2', offsetgroup=2)
    ],
    layout={
        'yaxis': {'title': 'SF Zoo axis'},
        'yaxis2': {'title': 'LA Zoo axis', 'overlaying': 'y', 'side': 'right'}
    }
)

# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT**

In order to make a horizontal bar chart, do the following:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
animals = ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(name='SF Zoo', y=animals, x=[200, 140, 210], xaxis='x', offsetgroup=1, orientation='h'),
        go.Bar(name='LA Zoo', y=animals, x=[12, 18, 29], xaxis='x2', offsetgroup=2, orientation='h')
    ],
    layout={
        'xaxis': {'title': 'SF Zoo axis'},
        'xaxis2': {'title': 'LA Zoo axis', 'overlaying': 'x', 'side': 'top'}
    }
)

# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: How can I make this horizontal?

Comment: @LoukasPap, I have edited the answer for you! <3

Answer (score 5):

For those coming across this post now, plotly now has a `offsetgroup` attribute in bar graphs that solves this issue. Setting `barmode='grouped'` still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a grouped bar charts with multiple axes: https://plot.ly/~etpinard/2080/grouped-bars-on-multiple-axes/

The corresponding python code can be found here: https://plot.ly/~etpinard/2080/grouped-bars-on-multiple-axes.py

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks but you have 2 separate graphs here. I was looking for a grouped bars of only two traces on a single x axis (like the zoo example [here](https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/)); with two y axes each on one side, one on the left and one the right, similar to the first example [here](https://plot.ly/python/multiple-axes/). Is this possible? Thanks !